# merge 2 vectors using STL algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I've 2 vectors, namely `deals_all` and `deals_new` of `FXDeal`, where `FxDeal` is a class

```
struct FxDeal
{
    int deal_id_; // primary key
    string ccy_pair_;
    double amount_;
}
```

Both vectors are sorted by the primary key field `deal_id_`.

How could I merge `deals_new` into `deals_all` so that

- new deals in `deals_new` are copied or appended to `deals_all`, and
- deals in `deals_all` that appear also in `deal_new` (by primary key
  `deal_id_`), will have field `ccy_pair_` and `amount_` updated

I'm using c++11.

Comment: Are the vector's sorted? Do you have any order requirement, i.e. any requirement on the sequence of elements in `deals_all`?

Comment: oh yeah it's sorted, let me update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::set_union`. (this assumes the vectors are sorted using a comparison function called `compare_by_id`, which does what the name implies).

```
std::vector<FxDeal> merged_deals;
std::set_union(deals_new.begin(), deals_new.end(),
    deals_all.begin(), deals_all.end(),
    std::back_inserter(merged_deals),
    compare_by_id);

deals_all = std::move(merged_deals);
```

Be sure you pass `deals_new` as the first range, because that will be the one which is copied over in cases of duplicate ids.

Comment: 'compare_by_id' I suppose is a Lambda?

Comment: How is the requirement "deals in deals_all that appear also in deal_new (by primary key deal_id_), will have field ccy_pair_ and amount_ updated" handled?

Comment: @athos: It could be a lambda, if you want. Or an object of a named function object class, or a function.

Comment: Thx now I got it

Comment: @Arun: I'm assuming that by that, the OP means that he wants those values replaced with whatever their value is in `deals_new`. If that is the case, then this behavior is specified by the standard documentation for `set_union`. If he wants some other behavior (like the amount values being summed), then this will not work, of course.

Comment: That's how I looked at it actually, i.e. the *update* can be of any type, like aggregating amounts (as in your example).

Comment: Consider `reserve()`ing some some space in `merged_deals`. Although it may not be straightforward how much is right :). Some options are `M`, `max(M, N)`, `M+N`.  I might choose `max(M, N)`. `M` and `N` are sizes of the two vectors.

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following (pseudo-code):

```
std::set<FxDeal> deal_set{deals_all.cbegin(), deals_all.cend()};

for (auto const& d : deals_new) {
  auto it = deal_set.find(d);
  if (it != deal_set.end()) {
     FxDeal x = *it;
     // update x with d.ccy_pair_ and d.amount_;
     // this allows adding amounts, for e.g. x.amount_ += d.amount_
     deal_set.erase(it);
     deal_set.insert(x);         
  }
  else {
    deal_set.insert(d);
  }
}

deals_all.assign(deal_set.cbegin(), deal_set.cend());
```

Comment: So there's no algorithm like std::for_each , std::transform etc to make life easier?

Comment: There are. I could not use them in this answer though. I have updated the answer,, please check now.

Comment: The elements of a `std::set` are const, so you won't be able to update them. You could try storing pointers in the set (and providing an appropriate indirect comparator).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That is a very good feedback. Thank you. Answer updated.